# Is using classes in Wordpress recommended?

Tags: php, wordpress

Small intro; I did two internships at the same company, for me it was a web development intro internship at first and the second time I kind of replaced my old teacher and worked as a normal employee. After the second internship I am now working here in my spare time after school.

I have been working on a semi-large european website and some other cool projects, but the websites suck! Atleast, under the hood. They are filled with function that make no sense and for almost every action a new function has to be created. Because around six people have been working on this website it is also filled with alot of different programming styles etc.

Now I am creating a completely new website that needs to be reusable as a quick temporary website for big projects. It needs to be responsive and simple. Now I am in control of setting up this website, I wanna do it good.

So what I did so far was start using GIT (did that 5 months ago for the other websites too), started learning SASS, started exploring responsive 'framework' themes for Wordpress (think i'm going to use Bones) and make a more logical folder structure for the files.

Okay now the interesting part:
Should I start programming in classes for Wordpress? A few weeks ago I got this idea that I should create a class for every custom post-type, this way I can easily create new posts, update them or get their data. Untill now everything I have seen was just a big pile of functions laying around, spitting out HTML, not much of a structure.

TLDR; What should I start doing to make my Wordpress website a bit more OO and overall clean to program in?

EDIT: This question was put on hold because it was opinion based, let's ask the question differently: Will using classes for (example) each post-types slow my Wordpress website down or break it somehow?

Comment: Welcome to the real world.

Comment: Can I suggest you remove the intro and simply ask the question? Ie, start with the fourth paragraph. It's great you want to do things right (it really is!) but the question should form the bulk of the, you know, question :)

Comment: ...and if you want it less opinion-based, ask about good Wordpress design - there's probably more to it than just classes / no classes. That will run the risk of being closed as poll-based, but unless it's a duplicate then IMO it's a valid learning question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Any application written in PHP should be written in class. While this is my opinion I'm sure a lot of people share it with me. I also develop wordpress plugin and I always code it using classes. My meta boxes are in classes, so are my widgets and custom post types. (let me know if you want some examples)

You could also have a look at this http://wpmvc.org/documentation/tutorial/
I didn't test it yet but I think it's a good start when creating plugins.

I see to many plugins with only 1 file and a lot of functions... If you download plugins like cart66 or other popular plugins you will see they are all coded with classes.

Basicly, if you want to write a proper application (under the hood) take the time to do it correctly.

ps: If you add custom post types, meta boxes and such, don't put those in your theme but add this in a plugin! Otherwise if you change your theme you will have to copy everything again. (If it has nothing to do with the layout of your site put it in a plugin)

Comment: MVC with wordpress? Either you are the generation's genius, or you aren't doing what you think you are.

Comment: really ... Why don't you explain it then

Comment: I create the theme from scratch (besides using Bones' start), what is the advantage of putting things like post-types in a plugin if I not use a default theme?

Comment: @krike: Wordpress is not OO by nature. You can try to hack it, but you can't really make it full OO. MVC? That's a whole league above OO. Which is why I say, if you manage to implement MVC with Wordpress, you must be something special. I'm not being sarcastic or insulting. I'm really interested in seeing what you've done.

Comment: @Gideon because if you change you pick another theme you would need to copy all your code to that theme. I'm not saying you have to follow my advice. But if it adds functionality to your site it should not be place in your theme. if you change your theme you break your whole site.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes i know Wordpress is not OO, it doesn't mean you can't have a basic MVC structure in your plugin.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha what does MVC have to do with OO? MVC is just a pattern that defines layers/compenents.

Comment: @krike: Again, I want to see what you did there.

Comment: @meze: It's true that MVC *can* be implemented without OOP, you know as well as I do it would get real ugly real fast.

Comment: @meze I would never code an application in OO without using MVC. They are not directly linked but mostly combined when programming.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ok no problem, I don't mind sharing how i coded my plugins and getting some feedback. But I'd rather mail it.

Comment: @krike: https://gist.github.com/ or even better use git and https://github.com. Better than mailing every day of the week :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha no sorry it's a private plugin and it is already in a git repo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33339/discussion-between-madara-uchiha-and-krike)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha and with OOP it may get ugly. I meant MVC is just higher abstraction than just objects. Your point would be valid if you said " MVC in PHP?" Because there's no view  ;)

Comment: @meze yes I see. I didn't mean MVC are classes, I know it is more than that. But I now understand i need to be careful how i mention it :)